# How do I use Foreach-Object to output the difference in time created for each item in a directory?

Tags: powershell

I've been looking all over Microsoft's docs but there's something I must not be understanding.

This command finds the files in the directory and outputs their name and creation time in a file. Almost perfect.

```
Get-ChildItem $dir -Force | Foreach-Object -Process {"$($_.BaseName) - $($_.CreationTime)"  } >> output.csv
```

Now I want to be able to select the time after the one its currently processing, and subtract them. For instance, instead of currently getting a big file like this:

```
0150 - 04/24/2021 03:43:57
0151 - 04/24/2021 03:45:58
0152 - 04/24/2021 03:46:38
0153 - 04/24/2021 03:47:59
0154 - 04/24/2021 03:48:00
0155 - 04/24/2021 03:50:00
0156 - 04/24/2021 03:51:06
```

I want it to output this:

```
0150 - 
0151 - 00::02:06
0152 - 00:00:40
0153 - 00:01:21
0154 - 00:00:01
0155 - 00:01:00
0156 - 00:01:06
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the previous value in a separate variable, re-assign at the end of each iteration:

```
$last = $null
Get-ChildItem $dir -Force | Foreach-Object -Process {
  $diff = if($last){
    '{0:hh\:mm\:ss}' -f ($_.CreationTime - $last.CreationTime)
  }
  "$($_.BaseName) - ${diff}"
  $last = $_
} >> output.csv
```